# Error using rmagick in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

I am getting following error when trying to run rails application:-

> /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/lib/RMagick2.so:
>   libMagickCore.so.4: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory
>   - /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/lib/RMagick2.so
>   (LoadError)
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in`
>   require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in
>   `new_constants_in'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in`
>   require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/lib/RMagick.rb:11
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `gem_original_require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`
>   require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in
>   `require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in`
>   new_constants_in'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in
>   `require'
>           from /home/amol/Amol_Backup/AMOL_BACKUP_20091021/PROJECTS/Fitsmi/life180/config/environment.rb:12
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   gem_original_require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in`
>   require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in
>   `new_constants_in'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in`
>   require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/commands/servers/webrick.rb:59
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `gem_original_require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in
>   `require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in`
>   new_constants_in'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in
>   `require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/commands/server.rb:39
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   gem_original_require'
>           from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `require'
>           from script/server:3

The file RMagick2.so is present in the given path /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/lib.

Following are the versions my application is using:-

rails 2.3.5
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.02
rmagick (2.12.2)
imagemagick 6.2.8.0-4.el5-5.3

Operating system:- Centos 5

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem on RHEL5 with the following changes:

- Create /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf
- add the following lines:

  /usr/lib
  /usr/local/lib
- run `ldconfig`

This fixed the issue for me. (On to the next dependency ..)

Answer (score 0):

What Linux system is this one exactly? It seems it is missing `libMagickCore.so.4`. If I look in my Ubuntu, I see it belongs to the package `libmagickcoreX", where the`X` stands for the version. The most I've seen int he last Ubuntu is version 3, but I've seen RPMs with version 4, so in your system you may be able to install that package version.