# My previues Rails Project does not work now, because of some error in RMagic gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rmagick

I programmed a website in Rails on Ubuntu 12.10.

after some while, when I came back to check it, when look at localhost:3000,
everything is ok until we click on anything, i see a page that say

libMagickCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/dare/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.so

i find this [Error using rmagick in rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408343/error-using-rmagick-in-rails-application)

but it's not useful for me.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: This is caused by a bad installation of RMagick.

Comment: it worked about 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think that libMagickCore belongs to imagemagick.
Try reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove imagemagick
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: Tnx for reply @daniloisr. I did what you say, but still doesn't work

Comment: i found [this case](http://www.42.mach7x.com/2010/07/13/help-im-getting-the-message-libmagickwand-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory-i-know-imagemagick-is-installed-what-should-i-do/), maybe you can search for libmagickcore using `find / -inane libmagickcore 2>/dev/null` and then create the links showed on the blog that I linked

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, also, when I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10.

Reinstalling the gem will get things working for you

```
gem install rmagick
```