# Passenger error: libMagickCore.so.2: cannot open shared object file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, imagemagick, rmagick

After upgrading CentOS, when I run my rails(4.1.4) application it gives an error

> libMagickCore.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory -
>   /var/www/html/greenbadger-rails/vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/rmagick-2.13.3/RMagick2.so
>   (LoadError)

I can't find libMagickCore.so.**2**, but I have libMagickCore.so.**5**

```
$ locate libMagickCore 

/usr/lib64/libMagickCore.so  
/usr/lib64/libMagickCore.so.5 
/usr/lib64/libMagickCore.so.5.0.0 
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.a 
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.la 
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so 
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so.5 
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so.5.0.0
```

Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Try to reinstall `rmagick` gem.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev Thx. I was trying, but It didn't help

Comment: Did you remove it first?

Comment: @NickVeys Yes, I did

Comment: Try to play with `ldconfig` as it provided in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408343/error-using-rmagick-in-rails-application?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I had to uninstall ImageMagick and ImageMagick-devel and download the rpm for the version of ImageMagick RMagick was looking for and install it manually:
yum erase ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel;
rpm -i ImageMagick-6.5.4.7-5.el6.x86_64.rpm